# Text is getting clipped at bottom of TextView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview

Here in this code, I want the overview section of the movie to get all the available space but the problem is that the end of the text gets cut off and seems odd.

Here's the image how it looks like.
Here the overview of movie is big and it doesn't fit the TextView so it gets clipped.

[image]

And here's the XML code I am using for my RecyclerView item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view_search"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:elevation="100dp"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_poster_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_search"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/image_view_poster_search"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_name_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_media_type_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_overview_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_year_search"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: try taking weight line off and give height wrap_content for overview textview..

Comment: but that will go beyond the allowed size for the textview...
textview should be contained within that limit.

Comment: which limit you have ? I dont see any limits

Comment: the whole information about the movie should not exceed beyond the poster of the image

Comment: to accomplish that you need to give textview max line or ellipsize will not work..

Comment: but max line will depend on screen sizes....
for 4 inch phone it will be les and for 5 inch phone it will be more.

Comment: so find textview's height dynamically.. i.e. total height of image - (heights of views linear layout search except overview textview)

Comment: For me, the text size being 12sp was what was causing it, I do not have a fix though

Answer (score 0):

remove bottom margin of textview

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_overview_search"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"//remove this line
```

and set bottom padding like

```
android:layout_paddingBottom="8dp"
```

Comment: it didn't work....and how this will solve the problem? The end result will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your text in a `ScrollView` to give the user a consistent card size and flexibility with the length of the information associated with each card.

Otherwise, have you tried changing to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in the TextView that is giving you problems?

Comment: yes doing wrap_content is increasing the hieght of the whole item..which i dont want.